# How to prevent FIFO Queue to suspend conditionally

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, tensorflow

The [FIFO Queue](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue#enqueue) will suspend in its `enqueue` and `dequeue` functions when queue is **full or empty** respectively. It is not a problem when you have only ONE queue.

My case is I have **TWO** queues, I have to enqueue with some conditions below:

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(timeout_in_ms=10000)
i1, l1, i2, l2 = produce_sample()

if l1 == l2:
    sess.run(enqueue_same_op, feed_dict={x1: i1, y1: l1, x2: i2, y2: l2}, \
             options=run_options)
else:
    sess.run(enqueue_diff_op, feed_dict={x1: i1, y1: l1, x2: i2, y2: l2})
```

`enqueue_same_op` and `enqueue_diff_op` are operations of `queue_same` and `queue_diff` respectively.

Because the probability that the `l1<>l2` is much **bigger** than `l1==l2`. So the session will suspend on enqueuing of the `queue_diff` even if I adopted the `run_options`.

Is there a way to **get the size** of the queue, or **test** if it is full?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the size of the queue, or test if it is full?

you can set the size of the queue using `size()` function and test against the queue capacity

```
capacity=1000 # your queue capacity
dtype=tf.float32
queue_diff = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity, dtype)
enqueue_op = tf.cond(tf.equal(queue_diff.size(), capacity), lambda:is_full(), lambda: enqueue(queue_diff, enqueue_elements..))

# a function to takecare when the queue is full
def is_full():
    return 'Enqueue_Failed'

# a function for enqueue ops
def enqueue(queue, element...):
    queue.enqueue(element)
    return 'Enqueue_Success'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of a queue by calling the [size](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue#size) method, which returns a tensor:

```
$ queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=100, dtype=tf.float32)
$ queue.size()
<tf.Tensor 'fifo_queue_Size:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
```

If you have a fixed size queue, like in an example above, you can condition the flow using `tf.cond` function and thus check if it's full.

Alternatively, you can use `capacity=-1` to make your queue unbounded. Strictly speaking, this is not in open API and not stated in the official documentation, but one can find it in the source code:

```
def _fifo_queue_v2(component_types, shapes=None, capacity=None,
                   container=None, shared_name=None, name=None):
  r"""A queue that produces elements in first-in first-out order.

  Args:
    component_types: A list of `tf.DTypes` that has length `>= 1`.
      The type of each component in a value.
    shapes: An optional list of shapes (each a `tf.TensorShape` or list of `ints`). Defaults to `[]`.
      The shape of each component in a value. The length of this attr must
      be either 0 or the same as the length of component_types. If the length of
      this attr is 0, the shapes of queue elements are not constrained, and
      only one element may be dequeued at a time.
    capacity: An optional `int`. Defaults to `-1`.
      The upper bound on the number of elements in this queue.
      Negative numbers mean no limit.
    container: An optional `string`. Defaults to `""`.
      If non-empty, this queue is placed in the given container.
      Otherwise, a default container is used.
    shared_name: An optional `string`. Defaults to `""`.
      If non-empty, this queue will be shared under the given name
      across multiple sessions.
    name: A name for the operation (optional).

  Returns:
    A `Tensor` of type `resource`. The handle to the queue.
  """
  result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("FIFOQueueV2",
                                component_types=component_types,
                                shapes=shapes, capacity=capacity,
                                container=container, shared_name=shared_name,
                                name=name)
  return result
```

If you are comfortable with this kind of dependency and you are sure the queue won't eat up all available memory, you can pass `-1` and thus greatly simplify your code.